# VS 2010's Productivity Power Tools's Tab Well on the Right Side

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I once managed to position the tab well vertically on the right side of VS's GUI by tweaking the registry. 
But I can't find out anymore how I did it.
Please refresh my memory.

EDIT : *Before having this recent interface (see answer), These were "hidden" option that needed to be tweaked like described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/21/document-well-2010-plus-hidden-options.aspx#gradientsforcustom)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools, Options, Productivity Power Tools, Document Tab Well, Advanced Options